# How do I query on two incoming models using the Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I've got the following models:

```
class DataStream(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

class DataStreamSubCategory(models.Model):
    data_stream = models.ForeignKey(DataStream)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class DataStreamExample(models.Model):
    data_stream = models.ForeignKey(DataStream)
    example = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So, each `DataStream` can have 0 or more `DataStreamSubCategory` objects and 0 or more `DataStreamExample` objects.

What I want to do is essentially display these values in a simple table in a template:

```
----------------------------------------
| Category | Sub-categories | Examples |
----------------------------------------
| Cat1     | Sub-cat1       | Ex1      |
|          | Sub-cat2       | Ex2      |
|          | Sub-cat3       |          |
----------------------------------------
| Cat2     | Sub-cat4       | Ex1      |
|          |                | Ex2      |
----------------------------------------
```

So what's the best way to query the database to get these data? The most obvious (but probably dumb) way is to do this:

```
data_streams = DataStream.objects.all()
for data_stream in data_streams:
    sub_categories = DataStreamSubCategory.objects.filter(data_stream=data_stream)
    examples = DataStreamExample.objects.filter(data_stream=data_stream)
```

But is there a more efficient way? Seems like a few SQL joins should be in order here, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this using the Django ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query it directly in the template like this:

```
<table>
{% for ds in data_streams %}
   <tr>
      <td>
          {% ds.category %}
      </td>
      <td>
          {% for subcat in ds.datastreamsubsategory_set.all %}
               {{subcat.sub_category}}
          {% endfor %}
      </td>
      <td>
          {% for example in ds.datastreamexample_set.all %}
               {{example.example}}
          {% endfor %}
      </td>
{% empty %}
   <tr><td colspan="3">No categories found</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I shall let you figure out the formatting yourself.

In the context, just send `{'data_streams': data_streams}`

Basically, for reverse foreign key relationships, you would do `object.lowercasemodelname_set.all()` to get the related object queryset.

Read more on [lookups that span relationships here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Or you could add  a `related_name` attribute and use that instead of `lowercasemodelname_set`

You might want to even consider [`prefetch_related` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) if you want to reduce the number of queries on the database

Comment: Awesome! I knew there had to be a simple mechanism built in to handle this.

Comment: So your example didn't quite work, but it's close. You need to add `_set` to the end of the model name in the template. So, `ds.datastreamsubsategory_set.all`. Thanks!

Comment: @Geoff You are right. I was thinking of specifying a related name, and missed this point. Thanks . i edited the answer

Comment: For this case with straightforward foreign key relationships I would recommend `select_related` rather than `prefetch_related`.